# Set a password of voice before opening any app by google assitant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

i'm currently working on an app like a vault that prevents you to open that app but only by your voice or fingerprint on the google assistant. But my question is that may be with fingerprint i can but by voice how?? cause i need to store the voice somewhere and then later compare it.. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

For starters - you can't check a user's voice on the Assistant. Google doesn't send you the audio of what the user has said. All you get is a text transcript.

However... what you want is already what is implemented by Google. Users who have setup voice recognition on their Google Home devices will be recognized by the Assistant when they say "ok google" or "hey google" and you will receive a unique userID for those users. You'll get the same ID the next time they try talking to you. If the Google Home doesn't recognize the voice, it won't provide the ID.

There are caveats with the voice recognition, and voices can be recorded and played back so this isn't a foolproof security method, but from what you have described, it sounds like Google already does what you want.